# Insufficient storage availalable when there is plenty

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory, samsung-galaxy-note-2

My Samsung Galaxy Note 2 started giving the insufficient storage available after trying to transfer app to my SDCard using [DroidSail Super App2sd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.droidsail.dsapp2sd&hl=en) lite.

I uninstalled it before realizing there's a problem and now cannot install it again to try to troubleshoot it.

I tried installing from Google PlayStore:

- AptoIDE
- and samsung app

some random apps and some successfully installed but the majority didn't.

I was running Android ver.4.1.1 and rooted and decided to upgrade to 4.1.2.

I upgraded successfully and rooted again but nothing changed.

I have:

- 5.34Gb/11.07GB available in the internal storage
- 24.61GB/29.81GB on the SD card and
- 0.92GB/1.75GB RAM.

I rebooted, cleared the RAM, unmounted SDCard and re-mounted but nothing worked.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution that might help lots of people. I was able to install rom toolbox pro, I tried to fix the permissions but that didn't help then I changed the setting under app2sd that was set to save everything to extSD regardless of what it is TO auto as it should be by default i think and now i can install anything from the playstore without getting any errors. I think Droidsail super app2sd changed that setting behind the scene. Anyone who played around an app like APP2SD and has the same issue as I did will probably be able to solve it using my method. Good luck!

Comment: lol I can't believe that fixed it... Thank you. I never would have thought of that and have had this issue for weeks now (with other fixes like factor wipe tried)